# Masking Currency for Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

just a little help on how to mask number to make proper currency value in Regular Expression with comma..
i made it this far..

```
 ₱\d*\.\d{2}
```

and it will mask

from 3342.34 to ₱3342.34

how to mask it with comma for every 3 digits? :)

thanks in advance..

Comment: Regex isn't the best solution for this

Comment: i'll gonna used it for TextEdit Control that mask with regular expression.. :) that's why i need it in regex form.. or maybe your can give another idea on how to mask it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you have to use regex, here is your answer:

```
₱(?>\d{3},)*\d{1,3}(>?\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This will accept:

- ₱10
- ₱100
- ₱100,1
- ₱1.1
- ₱100,512,423.15

Comment: thank you so much for the answer.. however i figured it out with this also.. ₱(\d{1,3},(\d{3},)*\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})?)